# Changing font color runtime Android

Tags: java, android

I am using EditText for getting userInput but the problem I am 
facing is that I want to change the font color at runtime but in the 
same Edittext as I am able to change the font type but as I change the 
font color it changes for the whole editext but I need to change the 
color for specfic text only .

And one more issue issue is that when making an edittext with the 
height more than the "fillparent" property I am getting the cursor 
postion in middle but I want it to be at the top always i.e. at the 
start ..

Is there any other widget available which will provide me the solution 
for both the problems?

Answer (score 4):

Alignment of text within an EditText widget can be controlled via gravity:

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

To attach markup objects to the EditText's content you can use the [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) interface:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editview);
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("one red word");
builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 4, 7, Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
editText.setText(builder, BufferType.EDITABLE);
```