# Android: how to align two text views based on length of text

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout in which two TextViews are to be displayed on the same line such that

If TextView1 is a short text, TextView2 should be immediately right to TextView1(IMAGE1) and if the TextView1 is a long text, TextView2 should be at right corner of the Layout on the same line(IMAGE2)

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

i use simple horizontal LinearLayout with android:layout_weight attribute and it worked like you want.
Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="teeeeeeeext1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: TextView2 is just sticking to the right border of the parent view regardless of the length of Text1. Even if length of text1 is small, text2 is sticking to right border of the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout like this..

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

edittext 1 will push edittext2 to its right...depending on text in it..

Comment: Here what happens is if TextView1 is long text,it is pushing TextView2 to right most that TextView2 is not visible.If TextView1 is small, then TextView2 is visible here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:maxWidth` property for first text view. So your layout would look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:text="sdfksdofsdfsdfsdfsadfgwagrswargweqrgeqrgqwergeqrgeqrg"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="text2"
    />
```

Comment: Keeping Hardcoded values for maxwidth is working for me.But can I adjust it according to length of TextView2. Because all the devices doesnt have same width layout.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I apparently misread (or did not read fully) your question. Just don't mind my answer - I vote for mxy's :)

The last time I had the same problem, I wasn't able to find or hack away a straightforward solution. Counting pixels was not an option (at least not for me). But I found a workaround that eventually led to the same display concept, and that was to use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html).

As I'm assuming you want two different TextViews because you want them to have different colors (or size, or style, or typeface). 
The idea is to use a single TextView for the whole thing, and prepare a SpannableString before doing `setText` on your view.

By using combinations of ForegroundColorSpan, TextAppearanceSpan, etc, you can make your single TextView look like different TextViews with different styles, sitting side by side, wrapping to the next line as necessary.

Links:

[Setting font color at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897072/changing-font-color-runtime-android)

[TextAppearanceSpan sample](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.java.shtml)